# SqlDataAdapter display print statements from stored procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to display the PRINT messages from Stored Procedures in C# ASP.NET?

I am using SqlDataAdapter because the sql statement will change. It could be a stored procedure, a simple select statement, or any query statement.

I want to display the PRINT messages in Stored Procedures using SqlDataAdapter. I was wondering is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do that using SqlDataAdapter. I just realized that I don't have SQL Server installed here, but I am fairly certain you can get the print statements using SMO, executing the procedure, and listening for ServerConnection's InfoMessage event. I didn't see many good examples of executing procedures with SMO, but there is one [here](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/59024/SMO-running-a-stored-procedure-in-C)

To catch the InfoMessage event, just type:

```
serverConnectionVariable.InfoMessage +=
```

You should then get intellisense... hit a few tabs, and it will build out the event handler for the InfoMessage event.

I'll check back in if I get a chance to install SQL server and see if I can provide more information.